# Document on click function not found

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which I hold in a master `.js` file:

```
$(document).on('click', '.closeicon', function closeNotif(duration) {
  doSomething
}
```

I have a link with class `closeicon` which when clicked fires the function, no problem.

How though can I close it manually from within another function in the same master file?

I'm trying:

```
function doSomethingElse (){
  closeNotif(duration)
}
```

But I get the error `closeNotif is not defined`

Comment: function `closeNotif` is local scope function. Moreover, its first argument is not duration, but event object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the context you have put the `function` keyword in, you have created a *named function **expression***, not a **declaration**.

Consequently, it doesn't generate a variable of the same name.

Use a function declaration instead. Then pass that to `on`.

```
function closeNotif(event) {
  doSomething
}

$(document).on('click', '.closeicon', closeNotif)
```